# Не восстанавливается background после colorAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Сделал стиль для изменения цвета background у border, все работает отлично за исключением того, что иногда AutoReverse не срабатывает и цвет не возвращается в исходный

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="BorderStyle1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2c2c2c"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="CadetBlue" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Не надо reverse, лучше на mouseleave повесить обратную анимацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

> When you don't want an animation to hold its value after it reaches
> the end of its active period, set its FillBehavior property to Stop.